# Css Textarea text with background color padding and border per entry

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea and an input under it.

It's like a chat where you type something in the input and click submit and then it goes to the textarea.

Now, what I need to do is to add a div with some padding, a border and background color to the text added to the textarea.

For example..I tyoe 'Hello' in the input .... click submit and it is appended into the textarea but with this css:

```
.entry {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? do you at least have the HTML of the textarea, the form, etc?

Comment: Your question is confusing without a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<textarea>` is a input element you **can not** style each line of textarea. you should use another `<div>` instead of `<textarea>` Like this,

```js
function sendMsg(){

  var msg = $("#msg").val();
  if(msg != ""){
  
    $("#chathistory").append("<div class='entry'>"+msg+"</div>");
    $("#msg").val('');
  
  }
return false;

}
```

```html
<style>
  .entry {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chathistory">
  
</div>
<form onsubmit="return sendMsg()">
<input type="text" id="msg">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert div in the textarea Element.
you can use another Element instead of textarea , for example another div